# How to get the html of this website using python requests?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to download html file from the following website:

https://www.avto.net/Ads/results.asp?znamka=Audi&model=&modelID=&tip=katerikoli%20tip&znamka2=&model2=&tip2=katerikoli%20tip&znamka3=&model3=&tip3=katerikoli%20tip&cenaMin=0&cenaMax=999999&letnikMin=0&letnikMax=2090&bencin=0&starost2=999&oblika=0&ccmMin=0&ccmMax=99999&mocMin=&mocMax=&kmMin=0&kmMax=9999999&kwMin=0&kwMax=999&motortakt=&motorvalji=&lokacija=0&sirina=&dolzina=&dolzinaMIN=&dolzinaMAX=&nosilnostMIN=&nosilnostMAX=&lezisc=&presek=&premer=&col=&vijakov=&EToznaka=&vozilo=&airbag=&barva=&barvaint=&EQ1=1000000000&EQ2=1000000000&EQ3=1000000000&EQ4=100000000&EQ5=1000000000&EQ6=1000000000&EQ7=1000000120&EQ8=1010000001&EQ9=1000000000&KAT=1010000000&PIA=&PIAzero=&PSLO=&akcija=&paketgarancije=&broker=&prikazkategorije=&kategorija=&ONLvid=&ONLnak=&zaloga=&arhiv=&presort=&tipsort=&stran=1

If I look at the source in Google Chrome, I can get the HTML without any problem. But, I want to download multiple pages with Python requests. However, if I try to get the html that way, I encounter an error.

Using:

```
response = requests.get(url) 
content = response.text 
with open('filename', 'w') as dat:
    dat.write(content)
```

I get the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

I also tried using "allow_redirects=False", however, if I do that, I get a faulty html, which only contains the following text:

```
Object Moved
This document may be found here.
```

I am wondering what to do to be able to download this html using requests in python.

If I add the header:

```
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36'
```

the code does run, but once again, not giving the html I'm looking for. The html it creates is just one like something like this

```
<html><head><title>avto.net</title><style>#cmsg{animation: A 1.5s;}@keyframes A{0%{opacity:0;}99%{opacity:0;}100%{opacity:1;}}</style></head><body style="margin:0"><p id="cmsg">Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker</p><script>var ...
```

Comment: If you fetch this URL using a tool like `wget`, you'll see it gets a 500 error ("Internal Server Error"), and the 500 error handler causes an infinite loop.  My guess is it is looking for a browser identifier, and you aren't supplying one.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your insight. How can I suppy a browser identifier?

Comment: even after adding my browser's user agent, although the code works, I don't get the right html.

Comment: Go into chrome, open the dev tools, open the Network tab. Go to the link in Chrome now. Click on the new request in the network tab. You can see what headers Chrome is sending that way, and try adding them to your request in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try define a header for your requests.get() function i.e.

```
headers = {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',}

url = <url-here>
page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

This fixed it for me.